# php file_put_contents giving me permission errors

Tags: php

The site I am working on- `http://24.236.131.128/`
This is a site using the snapchat API. I can log into my snapchat account and SHOULD see the snaps I have that are unopened.

I can log in just fine, and view my friends or list of snaps. I can NOT, however, get the image to display or save to the path.

I get a Warning:

> file_put_contents(media/download/from_lolnope47_to_lolnope47_id_959644398384684466r.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.php on line 114 View pic...

the `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\media\download\` folder has full permissions set to the IUSR account for IIS, not too sure if that's the problem?

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
Here is the function to download the snap:

```
if ($id == 'download')
{
    echo '<title>Download picture</title>';
    $snapchat = new Snapchat($_SESSION['name'],$_SESSION['pass']);
    $snapid = $_GET['snapid'];
    $sender = $_GET['sender'];
    $recipient = $_GET['recipient'];
    $data = $snapchat->getMedia($snapid);
    $prePath = 'media/download/from_'.$sender.'_to_'.$recipient.'_id_'.$snapid.'.jpg';
    if (file_exists($prePath))
    {
        $finalPath = 'media/download/from_'.$sender.'_to_'.$recipient.'_id_'.$snapid.rand(0,100).'.jpg';
    }
    else
    {
        $finalPath = 'media/download/from_'.$sender.'_to_'.$recipient.'_id_'.$snapid.'.jpg';
    }
    //echo "<img src='$data'></img>";
    file_put_contents($finalPath, $data);
    echo '<a href="'.$finalPath.'">View pic...</a>';
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to write the file (around line 114)?

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with folder permissions, double check that.

Comment: give me a second and I will post that code @wanasten.  As for permissions, almost has to be, because i uploaded the identical code to my website server and theres no issues there at all

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image to the same folder where your php script is, you also need to set permissions `all` to the same user that `php.exe` is running, in last case scenario set permissions `all` to user `everyone` ( this is dangerous!).
Try using the full path `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/media/download/...` instead of the relative path `media/download`

Comment: I literally copied the files to my offsite webserver, where it worked. I copied them back from there, and it works here now.